# Two forms submitting data to a single page - can the PDO be processed on the submitting page?

Tags: php, html, forms, pdo

I have a sign-up section to my webpage, which is split into 4 forms on 4 different pages. Each form also has an 'edit' equivalent so users that are already signed up can edit their profile:
[image]

The data entered by each user is added to the database using PDO statements.

By using `POST`, the data on 'signup_form1.php' is processed and submitted in the header of signup_form2, and so on. The same applies to the edit_form sequence. The fourth and final form for both signup and edit are processed on the buyerhub.php webpage.

My question is the following:

Is this the correct way to go about handling the data (ie the form data is actually processed on the next page rather than the page containing the form). If so then how would the buyerhub.php page determine whether the data has come from the signup form or from the edit form?

It seems to me that following the sequence of data is quite 'messy' if the form data is not processed on the same page as the form, and it also introduces some form of conditional logic if more than one form redirects to a webpage (in this example main_user_hub.php).

Comment: Any which way works, there are some jquery alternatives like this basic eample of multipage form but on one page http://xoxco.com/projects/code/multipage/  --- if you want to know which form is sending to what then i do that by setting as an example an input hidden for the form --- <input type="hidden" id="myform" value="myforma> />   ---  so i would know which form is Posting to what.

Comment: I dont want them on one page, although I do see the merits in doing it this way. And this wouldnt solve the issue with the signup and edit pages both linking to the final page. I like the idea of the hidden input on the form for the conditional logic on this final page though.

Comment: It just seems that as almost all forms submit data to *somewhere* that there isnt a framework whereby the form is filled in, the submit button is pressed, the data is submitted, and then the subsequent webpage is loaded.

Comment: Yes you can use that in forms 4, so Main user hub knows where the information came from and do whatever you want from there.